# How I can redirect the domain to the server with IP address and port?

Tags: ip, redirect, port

I have a VPS server. I have a system - `CentOS`.

I use the program - `node.js`. The application runs on the address and port: `31.3.79.11:3000/`

I want to write the domain without port to the browser. And to load applications from the IP address : `http://31.3.79.11:3000`

I want to write - `domain.com` - and I want to read the source application from the `http://31.3.79.11:3000`.

How can I redirect a domain to this ip and port?

Comment: If there is nothing else on the server then why not change the port to 80? http://m.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/12/how-to-run-apache-and-nodejs.php

Comment: I have the apache on port 80.

Comment: Have a read of that link, it talks about your exact situation.

Comment: Put your link as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link suggests using mod_redirect and/or a library to run Apache through node.js

http://m.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/12/how-to-run-apache-and-nodejs.php

The library:
https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy